# Jsoup selector syntax for href + target text into strings

Tags: jsoup

An answer to another question suggested I would best be served using JSoup in my Android project to parse the following response to a web call:

```
var OX_abced445 = '';
OX_abced445 += "<"+"a href=\'http://the.server.url/openx/www/delivery/ck.phpoaparams=2__bannerid=29__zoneid=3__cb=e3efa8b703__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fsomesite.com\'target=\'_blank\'>This is some sample text to test with!<"+"/a><"+"div id=\'beacon_e3efa8b703\'style=\'position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility:hidden;\'><"+"img src=\'http://the.server.url/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=29&amp;campaignid=23&amp;zoneid=3&amp;loc=1&amp;cb=e3efa8b703\' width=\'0\'height=\'0\' alt=\'\' style=\'width: 0px; height: 0px;\' /><"+"/div>\n";
document.write(OX_abced445);
```

I need to extract two bits from this response and store them in two strings.  I also know that the response will always be in the format shown above. I need the href url but not the img src url so I figure I should look for everything between `href=\'` and `'`. I also need to extract the target text, ie. `This is some sample text to test with!` that is encapsulated between the `_blank\'>` and `<"+"/a>`.  I have JSoup set up and connecting to the URL, retrieving the response but am having trouble with the selector syntax.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from your question slightly as I don't fully understand the particulars.

If you have a single hyperlink in an html document then you can select the link and text using

```
Element link_el = doc.select("a").first();
String href_url = link_el.attr("href");
String target_text = link_el.text();
```

If the html document has many links in it then you might want to select the bit that you want using getElementsByClass for a containing class.

Element relevant_el = doc.getElementsByClass("relevant-class-name").first();
   Element link_el.select("a").first();

And of course if there are many links then you will want to iterate over doc.select("a")

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I haven't been able to test out your suggestion due to some other bugs in my noob code but I will shortly.